# How to add text to .txt file for each file name with string concatenation in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I need to fill a text in a context directory opened with shift + right click, like the following code. How can I do this?

```
$dir=Get-Location; gci $dir | ForEach-Object {$temp=$_.Name; ";"+$temp > test.txt}
```

Thanks

Comment: It is returning only one row.

Comment: For me it's unclear what you're asking

Comment: I have a folder with a list of file. I want to retrieve the name of each file (without extension) and then add those names in a txt file. For each string i want to concatenate some other strings, in order to have a row for each filename.

Comment: 1st: Please add this to your question. Use the edit button. 2nd: You should avoid concats with `;` if you try to build a format like csv. PowerShell has Cmdlets to cenvert from and to csv.

Comment: Give an example of entry files list and of output file content

Answer (score -1):

Use join operator

```
(Get-ChildItem (Get-location)).BaseName -join ';' | Out-File D:\Test\Names.txt
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: post Error... did you change the path